# getting error on a parameter, "name not defined"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get this mini guestbook page on my webpage going.  Here is my Python code (using Google App Engine) and I keep coming back with an error on the line that says "posts=Posts(parent=wall_key(wall_name))<----It's saying wall_name is not defined?  But am I not defining it at the very top of the page?  Btw, I am VERY new to programming, as you can probably tell.

```
DEFAULT_WALL='Public'
def wall_key(wall_name=DEFAULT_WALL):
    return ndb.Key('Wall', wall_name)

class Post(ndb.Model):
    guest_name=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)    
    guest_message=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date=ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class guestbookHandler(myHandler):
    def get(self):
        wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',DEFAULT_WALL)
        posts_query = Post.query(ancestor = wall_key(wall_name)).order(-Post.date)
        posts=posts_query.fetch(20)

        template_values={
            'title': 'Intro To {{Programming}}',
                }

        template=jinja_env.get_template('guestbook.html')
        guest_name=self.request.get_all("guest_name")
        guest_message=self.request.get_all("guest_message")

        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values, guest_name=guest_name, guest_message=guest_message))    

    def post(self):
        wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',DEFAULT_WALL)
        post = Post(parent=wall_key(wall_name))
        guest_message = self.request.get('guest_message')

        if type(guest_message) != unicode:
            post.guest_message = unicode(self.request.get('guest_message'),'utf-8')
        else:
            post.guest_message = self.request.get('guest_message')

        post.put()

        query_params = {'wall_name': wall_name}
        self.redirect('/guestbook.html?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "E:\Documents\stage_4_work_session_2\work_session_4.py", line 159, in <module>

    class guestbookHandler(myHandler):

  File "E:\Documents\stage_4_work_session_2\work_session_4.py", line 178, in guestbookHandler

    post = Post(parent=wall_key(wall_name))

NameError: name 'wall_name' is not defined

INFO     2015-05-09 19:18:06,483 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here is myHandler info

```
class myHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        template = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return template.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))


#This code identifies the name of the wall
DEFAULT_WALL='Public'
def wall_key(wall_name=DEFAULT_WALL):
    return ndb.Key('Wall', wall_name)
#This Post class sets up the model for my datastore
class Post(ndb.Model):
    guest_name=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)    
    guest_message=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date=ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Are you using webapp2, or something else?  Can you post the whole stacktrace for the error?  Can you post `myHandler`?

Comment: Yes using webapp2, also jinja2

Comment: Here is the error message

Answer (score 0):

[`request.get()`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html) -

> The request object provides a get() method that returns values for
>   arguments parsed from the query and from POST data.

So `request.get()` gets the data from a POST form in your html code and not from your python app file. For this, usually, you should have a form in your html code which has a field with a `name="wall_name"`. Or to send a query string which contains the `wall_name` parameter. Your error shows you don't have the argument `wall_name` in your request.

And, secondly, if you want to use a default value for argument in `get()` method, you should use the `default_value` parameter:

```
wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',default_value = DEFAULT_WALL)
```

P.S. It would help if you put your html code too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the direct cause of your error, but I noticed this:

```
def post(self):
    wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',DEFAULT_WALL)
    post = Post(parent=wall_key(wall_name))
```

You've got a local variable with the same name as the function it's in.  This is not good.  <strike>At *best* what would happen is that function will be able to run once, but then it will cease to be a function, since its name was overwritten.</strike>

**Edit**: Actually, I tested this with a small function, and it didn't fail in the way I was expecting to, but I still think it's a good idea to change the variable name...

You should change the name of that variable (post), and it probably wouldn't hurt to change the name of the `Post` class as well.  Call it something descriptive, like `GuestBook_Post`.

Update:  I couldn't reproduce the "wall_name is not defined" error when I ran your code.  You could `import logging` and then log the value of `wall_name` with `logging.debug()` right before the problem line, and this may shed some light on the situation.